# Asyc support in Java

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am creating something similar to https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-chat/ where I am using DeferredResult for async processing. I am getting the error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.
```

I chose to go the java way because I cannot edit my web.xml file. So I have a bean in my root-context.xml file as:

```
<bean id="asyncSupport" class="packagename.AsyncSupport"></bean>
```

and here is my AsyncSupport class

```
 pblic class AsyncSupport implements AsyncConfigurer {

@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(200);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
} 
}
```

It does not seem to working. Still same issue. Am i doing it correctly? How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: The error message complains about servlets and filters not being configured, and tells you what you must do. But you're posting an unrelated piece of XML and Java code, which doesn't make servlets and filters asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.xml on the servlet configuration you have to set async supoprted true

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```